# I need to limit my choice in CheckListBox

Tags: delphi

I need to limit my choice in CheCkListBox.
No more than two selections from the list.
How to do it?

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of

    0: begin
       // No more than two selections from the list
       end;


    1: begin
        // Choice not limited
       end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get count of checked items:

```
function GetCheckedCount(const Cl : TCheckListBox) : Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to Cl.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Cl.Checked[i] then
      inc(Result);
  end;
end;
```

CheckListBox OnClickCheckEvent:

```
procedure TForm13.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
const // or global variable or ...
 MaxCheckedItems = 2;
begin
   if GetCheckedCount(CheckListBox1) > MaxCheckedItems then
     CheckListBox1.Checked[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex] := False;
end;
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Dim ItemsChecked As Integer = 0
Dim limit As Integer = 2 

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
 ItemsChecked = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
 If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count >= limit Then
  If e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked Then
      e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
  Else
      e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
  End If
 End If
End Sub